# OAuth to a service behind a firewall

Tags: oauth, vpn, firewall

We're looking to integrate Github enterprise into our service. However I know that many companies have on-prem deployments, possibly with internal access only to their Github enterprise endpoints.

I'm wondering how I can enable them to be able to use their Github enterprise APIs.

My current idea is that we can use the OAuth flow to get an access token and then pass the token to the client browser which can then make the API requests directly. If they can OAuth, they are probably on the network.

I think there are security issues with the methodology, but I can't think of any other ways short of deploying a proxy service within their firewalls.

Comment: Is your question "is this a good idea?"?

Comment: Partly or is there a good way to do this to make it a good idea. How to reduce the attack surface.